How does Next.js redirects to 404.html under the hood in static exports?
I have a website (let's call it example.com) built with Next.js, statically exported. When I type in a wrong address in the browser (i.e. https://example.com/wrong-addr), it redirects to /404.html, a default fallback file provided by Next.js. Here is what I think happening:

The server checks whether /wrong-addr/index.html exists. No, it
doesn’t.

The server checks whether /wrong-addr.html exists. No, it doesn’t.

The server gets lost and the browser displays browser-default 404 page.


But, instead of #3, Next.js somehow magically shows its own /404.html file. How can it do that? It seems that there was no chance for the server to run any js file or anything as it couldn't hit any real html file. No .htaccess or similar config exists either. What am I missing here?
I tested with static files that I manually created and they couldn't hit /404.html but returned browser 404 as expected in #3.
(Please note that I'm not asking about Next.js configurations or enabling routers.)

AFAIK Next.js isn't serving specific index.html files from specific directories, but instead still only has one root-level index html file that is served and is reading the rest of the URL request and checking the file structure for a matching page to render. Since there isn't a matching page it knows to return the generic 404 page. I could be wrong though.

@DrewReese thanks for your input. I think so too, but my question is how can it be redirected to index.html or 404.html without .htaccess configuration. It magically redirects wrong URLs to 404.html. I created 404.html manually and tested on the same server but it couldn't find 404.html without .htaccess.

It's not redirecting, as far as I understand, it's returning an "error page" for a page route that doesn't exist. Next.js has access to the files/directories behind the root directory, so it knows what is accessible as a page. Is the "404" part tripping you up? It's not a browser error. Would it be easier to think of it more like a notFound.html, some page content that is rendererd when you accessed a route without content?

@DrewReese Thank your for your input. After your comments, I eventually figured out and added an answer. It was a weird glitches if not my lack of knowledge.

Okay, I figured out. It was an issue when http-server handled an empty 404.html file.
http-server redirects all the wrong URLs to 404.html by default. That was why Next.js app showed 404.html contents. It was as expected.
Now, the question is why the other site that I manually created didn't hit 404.html. It was because the 404.html file was empty. I did touch 404.html but never wrote anything inside of the file. It turns out that http-server doesn't redirect to an empty 404.html but let the browser display browser 404 error. As soon as I wrote down a few words in 404.html, it just redirects to the file. (Duh...)
I'm not a server expert and do not know if this is a universal behavior on other html servers. However, it is worth checking if 404.html has actual contents in case it doesn't work properly.
Thanks @DrewReese for your input.
